# ! next to a number in a conditional prints true on strict comparison

Tags: javascript, triple-equals

```
console.log(false === 0) // false

console.log(false === !1) // true, why does it equate to true using !?
```

and vice versa for

```
console.log(true === 1 ) // false

console.log(true === !0) // true
```

I understand the difference between equality and identity but couldn't understand this behaviour of JS . Please explain ?

Comment: because 0 is a number and false is boolean

Comment: The `!` operator converts anything next to it to a Boolean.

Comment: `false === !1` evaluates to `false === !true` which evaluates to `false === false` which evaluates to `true` . The key part here is that the ! forces the JS engine to convert `1` to a boolean and then "not" it. Since if you convert `1` to a boolean you get `true` (it's a "truthy" value), the rest follows from that.

Comment: It sounds like you expect `!` to turn `1` into `0`…!?

Answer (score 6):

The `===` requires that both values are the same type, no implicit coercion is performed.

When you compare a boolean to a number with triple `===`, **you will always get false, since they are not the same type**.

**But using `!` in front of a number (or anything else) will convert it to Boolean first**, (`!x` is same as `!Boolean(x)`) so the strict comparison can succeed. (actually, using ! on anything will coerce it to a Boolean in JS)

---

**Rules of conversion number-to-boolean conversion :**

For the number-to-boolean conversion, `0` and `NaN` are coerced to `false`, and any non-zero number is coerced to `true`. (FYI, `null`, `undefined` and the empty string `''` are the only other falsy values in JS)

Now, you will have two boolean to compare, and === will return true or false accordingly.

So, to summarize :

in `!1`, 1 is non-zero, so it gets coerced to `true`, and `!true` gives `false`

so `false === !1` is equivalent to `false === false`, which is a true statement.

You can work out the details for the other comparison.

---

As an additional resource, if you have time and are interested in learning more, I recommend the very good free ebook "[You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#explicitly-----boolean)".

Answer (score 3):

Because **!1** is treated as a `boolean` value in JS whereas *0* or *1* are interpreted as `number`.

You can use JS `typeof !1` and `typeof 0` to see the difference.

Since, `false` is also a `boolean` type, matching it with `0` (number) will result `false`.

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @pac0 Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you do `false === 0`, it's comparing the boolean `false` to the integer `0`. In contrast, when you do `false === !1`, javascript converts the integer `1` to a boolean and the unary `!` acts as a "not" operation on what is effectively `true`. Since `1` is truthy in javascript, `!1` converts to `false`. And vice-versa.

```
console.log(0) // 0
console.log(!0) // true

console.log(1) // 1
console.log(!1) // false
```

Answer (score 2):

`!1` is a [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean) (because of the [logical NOT operator (`!`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT)).
[`true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Boolean_literals) and [`false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Boolean_literals) are also Boolean values.
`0` is a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Numeric_literals).

Values of different types are never [identical (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will first convert your inverted numer to a boolean:

```
console.log(false === 0)
-> false

console.log(false === !1)
-> false === false
-> true
```

and vice versa for

```
console.log(true === 1 )
-> false

console.log(true === !0)
-> true === true
-> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand the difference between an integer and a boolean?

```
console.log(false === 0)  // false
console.log(false === !1) // true
console.log(true === 1 )  // false
console.log(true === !0)  // true
console.log(!1)           // false
console.log(!0)           // true
```

Identity comparison checks that an object is *exactly that*, and 1 is not `true`, neither is 0 `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Because ! operator convert any value to Boolean type and you are checking against another Boolean that's why false === !1 is giving you true.